# How to make a expandable GridView with variable length items in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a split view pane, where I want to place a GridView. In the gridview, width of the items should be variable and left aligned. As well as I have a more button, where the items that are not fit in a row, should to be placed vertically. GUI of should to be like the image below:

[image: GridView Image]

In this above figure, 1 to 8 are the variable length items where the item 6-8 are placed under the more button as they are not fitted in the open pane length.

Code that I have tried like below:

```
<GridView x:Name="GridViewPane"
        Grid.Row="0"
      FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
      CharacterSpacing="1"
      CenterPoint="0,0,0"
      HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
      ItemsSource="{x:Bind data}"
      IsItemClickEnabled="True">
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:List">
        <Grid x:Name="TextBorder"
              Width="Auto"
              CornerRadius="14"
              BorderBrush="Aqua"
              BorderThickness="1"
              Height="24">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="9" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="16" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                   Height="9"
                   Width="9"
                   Source="/Assets/Images/page_ic.svg" />
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       FontSize="11"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                       FontWeight="SemiBold"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       FontStretch="Expanded"
                       Text="{x:Bind DisplayName}" />
            <Button x:Name="DeleteTagButton"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Height="16"
                    Width="16"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    >
                <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       Source="/Assets/Images/page_delete.svg" />
            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"
                               MaximumRowsOrColumns="1"
                               />

    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>

</GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add variable length items in GridView, you can try to use [WrapPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/wrappanel) from Windows Community Toolkit. Before using it, you need to add **Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls** nuget package and then override the ItemsPanel of GridView, for example:

```
xmlns:toolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"

<GridView.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal" AllowDrop="True">
        </toolkit:WrapPanel>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</GridView.ItemsPanel>
```

**Or** in that case, you can also try to use [Command bar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/app-bars) to achieve it.

Comment: This really helped me. Now, I have one more question, how can I bind the visibility of more button based on secondary commands availability? I am modifying the generic style where I found `Visibility="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=CommandBarTemplateSettings.EffectiveOverflowButtonVisibility}">`.